# How to revert to Google Hangouts from Google Chat?

Tags: google-hangouts

My close relative have a phone which have both Hangouts and Chat installed. Chat does not have integrated Voice and Video call function. IMO, Chat is significantly inferior than Hangouts. So I still prefer Hangouts over Chat to communicate.

It used to be a blue banner that says "Hangouts is being replaced by Google Chat". Today, when trying to use Hangouts, it just say that Use Chat in Gmail. This is even after uninstalling Chat and reinstalling Hangouts from Play Store. There seems to be no way out of it. For the time being, it can still receive calls. But since I have no way to bypass that "Use Chat in Gmail" splash screen, I cannot do hangouts.

Am I being force migrated? Is there a way to rollback?

Answer (score 2):

> Am I being force migrated?

Yes. This happened to me too, starting yesterday.

> Is there a way to rollback?

Not that I'm aware of. In addition to reinstalling Hangouts, I even tried using an older version (com.google.android.talk-35.0.327050771.apk). The older version didn't work either; it forces an upgrade to the latest version of Hangouts.

The only workaround I've found is that https://hangouts.google.com/ is still accessible, but if you're accessing it on your phone you have to use the desktop version of the site. The mobile version of the site redirects you to the Play Store.

You can also use Chat directly in Gmail. It doesn't have video calling per se. What you have to do is create a Meet link, send that to the person that you want to do a video call with, then join that call yourself. So three steps instead of one .

In case it helps searchability, the exact message of the screen is:

> ##### It's time for Chat in Gmail
>
> Hangouts has been replaced by Google Chat. Your conversations and new features are ready in Chat in Gmail. Learn more
>
> Open Chat in Gmail
>
> Prefer to use Chat separately from Gmail?
>
> Get Google Chat